# Warlock(Fiend)/Warlock(Hexblade) 'multi'class build balancing question

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, warlock, balance, multi-classing

I currently play a level 4 Blade-pact-Warlock with the Fiend-patron in my friend's campaign.  Even though Blade-pact was considered less than ideal, from what I've read, it seemed like the only viable option considering the character's personality.  I just discovered the Hexblade-patron in Xanathar's guide, whose level 1 features would mostly fix all that I have to complain about the build I picked.

Now, switching Patrons is no longer an option for this character.

The approach I wanted to take was to multiclass this character, and pick up Warlock level 1 again, but this time to pick the Hexblade-patron to pick up those Level1-features.  But the PHB doesn't offer any rules or possibility for multi-classing in the same class twice, (with pretty good reason, because it'd be confusing,) *but I'm really thirsty for those level 1 Hexblade-features*

I'm trying to put together a gameplan to convince my DM. I don't want to ask for freebies either, so Im looking for some insight in my interpretation of this 'multi'-class.

Since CharacterLevel 5 would be *Warlock 4(Fiend)/Warlock 1(Hexblade)* her Warlock abilities would still equal the ones listed in the fourth row of the Warlock level progression table(PHB p. 106), right?
However, the */Warlock 1* would suggest she'd get the first row of that same table all over again too -- that's what every other class gets after all, if they multi-class into Warlock right?  Thus getting 2 more Warlock-Cantrips, 2 more Warlock Spells Known (1st level only) and 1 more Spell Slot. (1st level?)

The Otherwordly Patron Feature is what I'm doing this for but also Pact Magic again?

The harshest reading to me seems to strike away anything she got before away completely.  But that seems like it would be a steeper price to pay than you would otherwise pay with other multiclass builds.  But getting 2 more cantrips and spells *within the same spell-list* seems a bit silly, not to mention that it's kinda weird to get access to this 3rd spellslot already (even if it'd be limited to 1st slot level)

My idea is to pretend like there was no multiclassing for the rows **Cantrips Known**, **Spells Known** and **Spell Slots**, but to still eat the level-delay on *Slot Levels, Invocations Known (& invocation level requirement), ASI's, Mystic Arcanum's* & *Fiend-Patron Features*, as a trade-off for the lv1 Hexblade-Features.

Is that a balanced way to trying to multiclass with the same class?

Comment: Hi Nanisnae, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. I've updated your question to tag it [dnd-5e] based on what you've said in your question. Also, whenever you reach 20 rep you're welcome to join us in [chat].

Comment: I'm not sure if you're aware (you're already in house rules territory) but by default in D&D 5e [you cannot multiclass into the same class you already have for different class features](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46700/1204), meaning Warlock 4 / Warlock 1 would not be allowed -- unless you're house-ruling something around that. (Or unless something changed in recent rules.)

Comment: Related: [Can A Warlock Change Patrons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117473/33707)

Comment: Does your table already utilize house-rules for character creation or would you be the first to ask for a homerew class?

Comment: why is switching patrons "no longer an option"?

Comment: If you'd like, it may be easier to help narrow down your question and help if you can jump into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat). Folks there would be happy  to assist.

Comment: I have edited your question quite a bit to try and make the language clearer.  Please review the edit to make sure that the question you are asking is retained.  If not, sorry, please edit it again to clean it up.

Answer (score 11):

Normally, you cannot multiclass into a class you already have.

However, you might want to talk to your DM about simply **switching your subclass** to Hexblade, if it fits your character concept better, and advance your character as a full Warlock (Hexblade) 4. You might roleplay this, maybe as a personal quest to find your true calling and true master, or you breaking from the Fiend's control only to fall into the hands of the Hexblade...

Comment: This seems to be the one that convince my DM in the end, thanks! :)

Comment: @Nanisnae Glad it worked out for you. Happy gaming! :)

Answer (score 4):

### Try talking to your DM about switching to Hex Blade.

I know you mentioned that you can't for some reason, but I think this is the cleanest option. There's plenty of roleplaying opportunities to be had here as well as a ton of backstory flavor. Maybe the Patron for the Hex Blade has been watching you and barters against The Fiend for control? Maybe your party has to defeat a mild demon to prove yourself worthy of breaking your old pact? The sky's the limit, here.

Or you could just ask to switch out your level 1 abilities. Dark One's Blessing traded for Hex Warrior.

### If your DM won't allow you to switch

...(but is for some reason okay with self-joining on class)...
I would just treat it like any other class. You lock yourself out of your capstone ability and you have two sets of spell slots to keep track of with varying levels. No different than a Warlock-Paladin, or a Sorcerer-Warlock.

### If you can't switch classes or multi-subclass

Try to work out a feat with your DM that feels balanced, but also gives you the feel/function you're working for. (example: I want an Eldritch Knight with a Battlemaster feel? Just take the Martial Adept feat)

Comment: I think I'm already on thin ice when it comes to switching with my DM haha, I switched backgrounds(Acolyte to Soldier) early on when I got around to thinking up a story for my character, and then switched Aasimar-stats from DMG-based to Volo's guide-based. Hence the preference for something not so switch-like.

Comment: @Nanisnae it's not your fault a new book came out with more options that fir what you're trying to achieve. wouldn't hurt to ask. Like I said: This could be a great side adventure in the next few sessions and give your party a chance to form some good bonds.

Answer (score 4):

Per the Adventure League rules, you can just change your character.

> **Character Rebuilding**
>
> We recognize that many players start out with a
>   pregenerated character, or might try out a
>   character class, race, or other option, and then
>   decide later that it wasn’t the play experience they
>   were looking for. As such, characters in the first
>   tier (levels 1–4) can be rebuilt after any episode or
>   adventure. A player cannot change a character’s
>   name, but can rebuild the character using the rules
>   as presented in this document.
>
> The character keeps all experience, treasure,
>   equipment, magic items, downtime, and faction
>   renown earned to that point. The character
>   replaces the old starting equipment (along with
>   any gold earned from selling it) with the new
>   starting equipment. If a character’s faction is
>   changed, that character loses all renown earned
>   with the former faction, and starts at 0 with the
>   new faction. Characters that are level 5 or higher
>   cannot be rebuilt.

Perhaps you can convince your DM to establish the same rule. You're currently level 4 and would fall within the first tier. Plus you wouldn't have to wait to gain another level.

Comment: Not everyone accepts AL and there is no AL tag here.

Comment: @VoromirKadien, The OP specifically asked for _"put[ting] together a gameplan to convince my DM"_. Pointing to a documented rule from an official WOTC source sounds like more of a game plan than than trying to talk the DM into something specifically not allowed, multiclassing as two versions of the same class.

Comment: I think that while the other comments have been valid, this is the only one that actually answers the question as asked.